# Add margin or fix the element beloif h3 or any other tag is naturally breaking-line

Tags: html, css, sass, word-wrap, line-breaks

Hi everyone hope you are doing great,

I'm sending this message because i'm fixing an issue..

I have a `<h3>` tag who is breaking line but not everytime only when he is too long (logic :p) and sometimes i have other who are not but i would like to keep the same alignment between them

In this JsFiddle you'll see there is 3 `card__content` and i would like the `COMING - 01/03 to 21/03` middle stay even if there is no line break and fixed at the same level of the others am i missing something ?

https://jsfiddle.net/Morraycage/gdqekrvo/38/

Thank you by advance :D

Comment: You could add `margin-bottom: auto;` line 17.

Comment: Exactly what i needed you're the best thanks i totally forgot i was in a flex so i could use the auto --"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flex is awesome.

```
.card__content {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sawacrow/2or8u7g4/1/